No jump of hypersingular integral near boundary under lower regularity
Let $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a $C^2 $ smooth simple closed curve, the elasticity double layer potential on $\Gamma $ is defined as
$$
(Wu)(x):= \int_\Gamma (T(\partial_y,n(y))E(x,y))^T u(y) ds_y, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \Gamma
$$
where the fundamental solution of elasticity
$$
E(x,y) := \lambda' \delta_{ij} \ln \frac{1}{\vert x-y \vert} + \mu' \frac{(x-y)(x-y)^T}{\vert x -y \vert^2}
$$
$$
\lambda' = \frac{\lambda + 3\mu}{4\pi \mu (\lambda + 2\mu)}, \quad \mu' = \frac{\lambda + \mu}{4\pi \mu (\lambda + 2\mu)}
$$
2D-Traction operator
$$
T(\partial_y,n(y)) u  :=\lambda n_y \textrm{div}u + 2\mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial n_y} + \mu n_y \times \nabla\times u
$$
In the third term,
$$
n_y = (n_1(y),n_2(y),0)^T, \quad \nabla = (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2},0)^T , \quad u = (u_1,u_2,0)^T .
$$
Now we would like to prove no jump of traction derivative of double layer potential near the boundary, that is,
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} (T(\partial_x,n(x)) W (x +h n_x) - T(\partial_x,n(x)) W(x - hn_x)) = 0, \quad  \forall x \in \Gamma
$$
where
$$
T(\partial_x,n(x)) W (x +h n_x):= T(\partial_x,n(x)) \int_\Gamma (T(\partial_y,n(y))E(x+hn_x,y))^T u(y) ds_y
$$
$$
T(\partial_x,n(x)) W (x - h n_x):= T(\partial_x,n(x)) \int_\Gamma (T(\partial_y,n(y))E(x-hn_x,y))^T u(y) ds_y
$$
$n_x$,$n_y$ is the normal of $x$,$y$ directed into the unbounded domain.
Suppose that $u \in C^{1,\alpha}(\Gamma) $, with observation that
$$
T(\partial_x,n(x))W u (x) = \frac{d}{d s_x}  \widehat{V} (\frac{d u}{d s_y})  (x)
$$
$$
\widehat{V} \chi(x) = \frac{\mu(\lambda + \mu)}{\pi (\lambda + 2\mu)}\int_\Gamma (\ln \frac{1}{\vert x-y \vert} + \frac{(x-y)(x-y)^T}{\vert x -y \vert^2}) \chi(y) ds_y 
$$
and Gunter derivative in two dimension, we could prove no jump relation.
Now suppose that $u \in C(\Gamma)$, the result of no jump for harmonic double layer potential is known, how can we prove the elasticity case? We try the method in the Laplacian case but failed.
Note: The result in three dimension is known as the first Liapunov-Tauber theorem and can be found in [Kupradze79]. For details of some terminologies, we refer to [HsiaoWenlend08].
References:
[Kupradze79] Three-dimensional Problems of the Mathematical Theory of Elasticity and Thermoelasticity, North Holland Amsterdam, 1979.
[HsiaoWenlend08] Boundary Integral Equations, Springer-Verlag, 2008
